# filter an email before inbox

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook-addin

hello first of all sorry for my English  i want to filter email before reach to inbox for example if some one send email inside the organization first i have to check if the email is not a spam then allow to inbox and if email is spam or simple black list then directly delete 
i have tried

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.
    Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(
    ThisAddIn_NewMail);


        }
        private void ThisAddIn_NewMail()
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
                ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
                (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items items = (Outlook.Items)inBox.Items; 
            Outlook.MailItem moveMail = null;
            items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = inBox.Folders["Test"];//create a test folder first in your outlook box 
            foreach (object eMail in items)
            {
                try
                {
                    moveMail = eMail as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (moveMail != null)
                    {
                        string titleSubject = (string)moveMail.Subject;
                        if (titleSubject.IndexOf("Test") > 0) //send email to inbox subject test
                        {
                            moveMail.Move(destFolder);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do that. Application.NewMail or Items.ItemAdd on the Inbox folder is the earliest you can access the new message. Outlook will see it at the same time.

Comment: is their any other method filter email before it reach to inbox ??

Comment: No. Not unless it is your code that retrieves and creates the new item.